# Populate Enumerable.ToList with one line of code

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

Please see the person class below:

```
public class Person
    {
        int _id { get; set; }
        string _name { get; set; }

        public Person (int id, string name)
        {
            _id = id;
            _name = name;
        }

        public Person()
        {
        }

        public IEnumerable<Person> GetPeople()
        {
            _id = 1;
            _name = "James";
            yield return this;

            _id = 2;
            _name = "Michael";
            yield return this;

            _id = 3;
            _name = "Sarah";
            yield return this;
        }
    }
```

and the client code below:

```
Person p1 = new Person();
IEnumerable<Person> personEnumerable = p1.GetPeople();
List<Person> personList = personEnumerable.ToList();
```

Why does PersonList contain three entries for Sarah after this has run? What is the best way to populate personList in the client?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. What is the expected outcome?

Comment: @Jamie R, thanks.  I think the answers below have understood my question.  Please see the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably have seen this behaviour, right?

```
var p1 = new Person(1, "Tom");
var p2 = p1;
p2._id = 2;
// now p1._id is 2 as well!
```

This is exactly what is happening here. After the first `return this`, `this` is modified again with id 2 and name Michael. This causes the returned `this` to change as well, because they refer to the same object. You never created a new object using `new`. The same thing happens with the third yield return.

To fix this, simply change `Person` to a struct (so it's now a value type), or implement the method like JanDotNet did in his answer.

Answer (score 6):

Because `GetPeople` doesn't create new instances but modify the current one and returns it 3 times.

The following code produces the expected result:

```
    public static IEnumerable<Person> GetPeople()
    {
        yield return new Person(1, "James");
        yield return new Person(2, "Michael");
        yield return new Person(3, "Sarah");
    }
```